# Display image based on number value JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a number of details about a product which I wish to display. In my db the status of these items is stored as a number eg 1 - Worldwide, 2 - Europe Only, 3 - US Only

I currently use:

```
<h:outputText value="#{product.value}" />
```

Instead of the number I would like to display an image instead. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have images with filenames like `status1.gif`, `status2.gif`, `status3.gif` and display it as `<h:graphicImage>` with a "dynamic" filename as follows:

```
<h:graphicImage value="status#{product.value}.gif" />
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Really simple and easy solution. Thanks for that mate

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq to learn how Stackoverflow works.